# Luminosity distance as a function of redshift

Tags: cosmology, distance

We know that the luminosity distance is:

$d_L = a_0 R (1+z)$

with $z$ the redshift. How can we mathematically make explicit the dependence of $d_L$ from the redshift? I guess we need to make it explicit the dependence of $R$ from $z$, but how is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but assuming items with significant redshift and the lack of an ability to measure the distance leads me to assume that you are talking about remote stars. In which case:

1) We know the luminosity of certain stars (aka standard candles. A specific type which always has an event with the same brightness).

2) We know the red shift because the spectrum of specific elements is known and that pattern gets shifted.

Comment: @Hennes thanks for your answer but I was referring to a mathematical connection between the luminosity distance and the redshift. I want to explicitly determine the luminosity distance as a function of redshift.

Comment: This isn't my field but I think you're getting confused between different definitions of distance. You seem to be asking whether there is a relationship between distance and redshift, right? The relation you cite connects the "putative" distance $d_L$ of something worked out from its luminousity (grounded on Euclidean geometry) to a transverse "comoving distance" $R$. $R$ allows you to calculate the distance between two objects in the sky with the same redshift: we get $R \Delta\theta$ where $\Delta\theta$ is the angular subtense of the line joining them. In a flat universe, $R$ is also ...

Comment: ... the same as the distance from us to the measured objects. You calculate $z$ as a function of $R$ through Hubble's law to get the "proper distance", then you must correct this latter to $R$ using known equations from the FLRW metric. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance#Uses_of_the_proper_distance and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_distance

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but aren't you simply looking for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measures_%28cosmology%29#Overview)? Also, forgive me for editing your post, but the capital z for redshift hurt my eyes :)